# Бесконечный цикл for в java

Tags: java, циклы

Почему при таком построение цикла `for`, получается бесконечные вывод нулей?

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: меняем `i=i++` на `i=++i` и о чудо...магия в постфиксном и префиксном инкременте

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ваше выражение: **`i = i++`**. Что здесь происходит по шагам:

1. Сначала **`i = 0`**.
2. Вычисляется значение после знака равно. Это ноль: **`result = i = 0`**.
3. Вычисляется постфиксный инкремент. Теперь **`i = i+1 = 1`**.
4. Результат выражения записывается в **`i`**. В итоге: **`i = result = 0`**.

---

Можно заменить на: **`i = ++i`**. Тогда:

1. Сначала **`i = 0`**.
2. Вычисляется префиксный инкремент. Теперь **`i = i+1 = 1`.**
3. Вычисляется значение после знака равно: **`result = i = 1`**.
4. Результат выражения записывается в **`i`**. В итоге: **`i = result = 1`**.

---

В общем, постфиксный инкремент в операторе присваивания над той же переменной ничего полезного не делает. Отсюда и Ваш бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Но проще написать `i++`, без присваивания.

Comment: @VladD несомненно) Я думаю, вопрос был чисто теоретического плана.

Comment: в этом бы ответе в 1 пункте я бы разделил i и i_temp думаю понятнее переход 2-3 был.

Comment: >...Теперь i = 1. Найденное значение записывается в i. В результате i = 0.

@AivanF. Это как так?)

Comment: @free_ze да просто :) значение выражения было найдено, оно равно нулю. После инкремента над i оно так и остаётся нулём, в конце концов записывается в i.

Comment: @free_ze мой комментарий прочитайте. Если по простому, то сначала превычислится выражение (i++) = 0 (именно 0, ++ потом будет) потом сделается ++, а потом предвычесленное занесётся в i через =.

Comment: @pavel спасибо за совет, добавил в ответ для наглядности.

Answer (score 3):

Оператор `i++` есть краткая запись `i=i+1`. Но есть вариант написания `++i` или `i++`.

Разница в том, когда происходит операция инкремента, до обращения к переменной или после. В Вашем случае сначала значение `i` присваивается переменной `i`, а потом происходит инкремент, но значение его не сохраняется.

Вот если вы напишете `++i`, тогда все как надо будет работать.

Comment: ой не надо так делать. В С и то и то UB было бы.

Comment: Соглашусь. И хоть вопрос не по С был, но скорее у ТС была проблема с пониманием префиксного и  постфиксного инкремента

Answer (score 2):

Нужно исправить в последнем значении параметров цикла на:

```
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       System.out.println(i);
    }
```

В твоем случае после каждой итерации цикла ты присваиваешь i = 0 (так как ++ происходит уже после присваивания), и цикл снова обрабатывает i=0

Comment: Вы объяснили, _как_ нужно делать, но было бы неплохо ещё объяснить, _почему_ код ТС не работает. (В C++, например, такой код вовсе UB.)

Comment: а всё же, почему бесконечный цикл? Почему `i` не увеличивается хотя стоит `++`?

Comment: и что, что `++` после присваивания? Он же всё равно значение увеличить должен...

Comment: @pavel с чего бы это `i` должна увеличится, когда ты всегда будешь присваивать `i = 0;`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев ну если по логике (я знаю почему оно так не работает, но не всем это очевидно),  сначала мы делаем `i = 0` потом `i++` и становится равно `1` Или когда мы делаем `i++` ?)

Comment: @Werder, вы не правы. Присвоение выполнится только один раз - в момент захода в цикл. После каждой итерации будет выполняться только третий, а затем второй блоки цикла FOR.

Comment: @VladD Объясните, почему в C++ это UB? Неоднозначностей вроде `i+++j` нет, должно быть все хорошо.

Comment: @free_ze: Потому что `i` изменяется дважды в пределах одного выражения (это формально не совсем точно, но почти правильно), а порядок вычисления кусков (в отличие от Java) не определён.

Comment: @VladD Ах, ну да, совсем забыл про это. Спасибо! http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: @free_ze: Да, именно оно.